# Extract name from emails using a list of names to compare

Tags: google-sheets

My list of subscribers, the majority of them have not enter a name but in their emails 1 from 10 has name in it.

For example rose.84@example.com "Rose" is the deducted name.

So I will like to Vlookup on a list of 4000 names that I have and compare that to all emails and extract the ones that it finds.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=proper(trim(substitute(regexextract(A2, "^[A-z.]+"), ".", " ")))
```

Then use `filter()` or `vlookup()` to match the two lists.

See
[regexextract()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3098244),
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197)
and
[vlookup()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula: =REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^\w+")